Revalidate parameter not working in getStaticProps
I’m trying to make the revalidate option of next.js getStaticProps on Vercel but it doesn’t seem to be working.
Here is how my code looks like (roughly):
export async function getStaticProps() {

  const response = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.API_URL}/endpoint`,
    {
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
        Pragma: "no-cache",
        Expires: "0",
      },
    }
  );

  return {
    props: {
      response.data
    },
    revalidate: 3600,
  };
}

Even after going to the page multiple times a day it just won’t update. I’m using the free tier btw.
